# LayoutParams using AddRules

Tags: java, android, webview, android-relativelayout

I know there are related questions but please try my code 1st

I think my code is correct but I don't know why I can't get want I want

I'm trying to Replace the image into a RelativeLayout with the same LayoutParams dimension and placement(programmatically) then inside that RelativeLayout put a WebView in the center of it. 
It was almost done but I'm having trouble for the placement of Webview.
see the images below

activity_main.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.........
    // Image
    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    // Container of the image
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_imageView);
    loader(rl , image);
}
public void loader(RelativeLayout rl,View view){
    // Creating RelativeLayout
    RelativeLayout rlnew = new RelativeLayout(this);
    // Getting the Layout Parameters of the image such as (position and dimension)
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    // Coloring the background of the new Relative Layout into blue
    rlnew.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    // passing the parameters to the new relative layout from the image
    rlnew.setLayoutParams(lp1);

    // image turns into invisible
    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    // Creating a webView
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);
    // load the loading.gif
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", "<center><img src='loading.gif' style=''/></center>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
    // setting up dimension(height and weight) for the webview
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 60);        
    // adding position(Center) for the webview
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    // setting up Layout parameters for the webiview
    webView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    // adding the webview to the new Relative Layout
    rlnew.addView(webView);
    // adding the new relative layout into the container
    rl.addView(rlnew);
}
```

activity_main xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#ec0c0c"
    android:id="@+id/rl_imageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

     <!--Desired Output-->
    <!--<RelativeLayout-->
    <!--android:layout_width="70dp"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="70dp"-->
    <!--android:background="#010e6e"-->
    <!--android:layout_alignParentTop="true"-->
    <!--android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">-->
        <!--<WebView-->
        <!--android:layout_width="60dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="30dp"-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/imageView"-->
        <!--android:layout_centerVertical="true"-->
        <!--android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />-->
    <!--</RelativeLayout>-->

     <!--Default Image-->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/sample1"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
    </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[Output Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh9U2.png)

**I'm making a method that will ask for two parameters a RelativeLayout(that contains the second parameter of the method) and View so it can be anything like(Image, TextView, RelativeLayout , etc.,).**

This code can replace a specific View like a relativeLayout or textView or Image
and replace it with a relativeLayout with the same size and position of the given View(mine was the image)(It was already Done if you move that image anywhere in the given container the code will replace the image into a relativeLayout no matter where it is as long inside of the given container).

The only problem is the WebView position. . why is webView there?. .I want it in the center of the new RelativeLayout

Can someone tell where did I go wrong
If you have another way just submit answer

Comment: try remove `yourView.setLayoutParams` to add them directly like `rlnew.addView(yourView, params);`

Comment: @John Did you see the images? Same output. It did not get what I want.

Comment: Thats a total disaster, reusing LayoutParams is a source of problems, much better if you create a clean layout instead of using xml and messing it like that, and, listen to John comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but your xml is not. Try to change your xml below and test again:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="your dimen in dp < rl_imageView. width"
        android:layout_height="your dimen in dp < rl_imageView. height"
        android:src="@drawable/sample1"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
    </ImageView>
```

P/S: I suggest create this `Imageview` programmatically also.

Comment: . I edited my post. . the given View should be already exist in the layout. . I give more details to it. . so anyone can understand what is this for. .

Comment: Did you change the `wrap_content` from `ImageView` to specific dimen like `100dp` and test it again? Is that working or not? I have tried your code with specific dimen and it worked. The problem is `wrap_content` from xml.